# How do i stop the name repeatin itself at 10,000 times using timer?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, console-application

How do i stop the name from repeating itself at 10,000 times.. Right now it repeats every 5 seconds.. but in 24hrs, it should only repeat a maximum of 10,000 times.. How do i stop the timer at a given time?

The program ---:

```
class Timer1
{
   public System.Timers.Timer aTimer;


   public static void Main() 
   {
       System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
       aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
       aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
       aTimer.Interval = 5000;
       aTimer.Enabled = true;
       Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Exit the Program");
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name YaP {0}", e.SignalTime);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;

namespace Time_Writer
{
    class Program
    {
        static int count = 1;
        static double seconds
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(aTimer_Elapsed);
            aTimer.Interval = 8600;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Exit the Program\n");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        private static void aTimer_Elapsed(object source,ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Current time is :{0}\n ", e.SignalTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());

            seconds += 8.6;
            count += 1;
            if (count > 5 || seconds == 43) //change count to 10000, seconds to 86400
            {
                aTimer.Enabled = false;

                Console.WriteLine("Timer is off at {0}\n\n",e.SignalTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());

                //Reset variables and re-enable the timer if you desire to.
                count = 0;
                seconds = 0;
                aTimer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I hope this helps you with your answer always glad to help!
Visit the link below for more help.

//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.elapsedeventargs.signaltime.aspx

Comment: hey greg thank u so much. it did help me alot. can i keep in touch for further assistance?

Answer (score 2):

Add a variable to keep track of how many times its been fired (`count`), and increment it each time it's fired. Once you hit 10,000 (or any other number), set the timer's state to stopped via `stop()`.

```
class Timer1
{
   public System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
   public static int count; // Keeps track of how many times its been fired

   public static void Main() 
   {
       count = 0; // Initialize to zero
       System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
       aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
       aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
       aTimer.Interval = 5000;
       aTimer.Enabled = true;
       Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Exit the Program");
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(count >= 10000) // Check
        {
            aTimer.stop(); // Stop the timer
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Name YaP {0}", e.SignalTime);
        ++count;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Counter as per your requirement rather then the time calculations. If you need that it will run after every x minutes or x seconds then it is feasible to calculate time. Right now you want it to run 10000 times then increment counter at every Elasped event raise. when  it is 10000th time then disable Elasped event to fire by `aTimer.Enabled = false` or `aTimer.Stop()`.

class Timer1 
    { 
       public System.Timers.Timer aTimer; 
       public static int counter;

```
   public static void Main()  
   { 
       counter = 0;
       System.Timers.Timer aTimer; 
       aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(); 
       aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent); 
       aTimer.Interval = 5000; 
       aTimer.Enabled = true; 
       Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Exit the Program"); 
       Console.ReadLine(); 
   } 
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
    {     
        counter = counter + 1;     
        Console.WriteLine("Name YaP {0}", e.SignalTime); 
        if(counter == 10000)
        aTimer.Enabled = false;
    } 

}
```